# Completely silent robocopy

Tags: robocopy, silent, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to robocopy some files silently. Right now, I have robocopy putting everything into a log file, which is fine, but after it finished, `Log File: C:\<logfiledestination>` is printed. My command looks like this:

`robocopy source destination /mir /xd .svn /log:log.txt /np >nul 2>&1`.

From searching online, I thought that `>nul 2>&1` would have prevented anything from showing up. I'm extremely new to the windows command line, so if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know!

Edit: I had a phantom half-sentence in there that I missed. Fixed now though.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Does robocopy have a quiet switch (/q maybe?).  BTW, The interpretation of >nul 2>&1 is "redirect stdout to nul and redirect stderr (file handle 2) to stdout (file handle 1) and therefor to nul.

Comment: Thanks. robocopy doesn't look like it has a quiet switch; is it possible that robocopy is printing to console and not stdout?

Comment: Nevermind. That command is working fine. My real problem is actually coming from perl, since I am using the `system` command to call that command in a perl script. The `>nul` is not hiding the output from perl, so it's still showing up in my perl output.

Comment: I guess I was searching for the wrong answer. My final solution comes from calling the above command using backticks instead of perl's `system`. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 16):

These switches worked for me:

```
/NFL : No File List - don't log file names.
/NDL : No Directory List - don't log directory names.
/NJH : No Job Header.
/NJS : No Job Summary.'
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of each abbreviated switch.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7487697/ for a "more complete" list of the silencing switches

Answer (score 3):

It looks like these two options may be of help to you:

```
/NJH :: No Job Header.
/NJS :: No Job Summary.
```

Comment: This deserves more votes than the 4-switch answer. This is only 2 switches,  and should be the answer.

Comment: on further experimentation, your 2 switches aren't enough to suppress messages in all cases :(